# Number systems as subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

is $\mathbb{Z}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$? 
My conclusion was no, because I wanted to check three things: Does it contain the $0$ vector, is it closed under addition and is it closed under scalar multiplication.

The first two ones I found to be ok, but the last one is where I disprove it. If we let c $\in$ $\mathbb{R}$ and $u \in \mathbb{Z}$ then it is obvious that we if pick some non-integer $c \in \mathbb{R}$ then $c*u \in \mathbb{R}$ and not in $\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $\mathbb{Z}$ is not a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$.

However I read the following on a page I found online: "For example, the integers Z is contained in the real numbers R. Moreover, the addition and multiplication are compatible: The equalities 1 + 2 = 3, 2×3 = 6 hold either as integer operations or real number operations. Therefore we call Z a sub-number system of the number system R".

Is my conclusion wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your conclusion is not wrong, since indeed $\Bbb{Z}$ is not a *vector subspace* of $\Bbb{R}$. The axioms of a subspace are just not satisfied, as you have shown. Of course, it is a subset of the real numbers, but this is something else.

Also $\Bbb{Q}$ is not a vector subspace of $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: If I define vectoraddition as the usual addition of numbes and scalar multiplication of a real number $c$ and a whole number $u$ by $c*u = [cu]$ where $[cu]$ means the number $cu$ rounded down to the closest integer, does this now make $\mathbb{Z}$ a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ given my definitions, seeing as it now satisfies closed under scalar multiplication as well?

Comment: If you consider $\mathbb{R}$ as a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, then $\mathbb{Q}$ *is* a vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}$...